# Getting segmentation faults when flipping image

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I'm running this code, I keep getting segmentation faults.  I know segmentation faults occur when there's not enough memory allocated to the array.  Does anybody know where the seg fault is occuring at?

```
void flip_horizontal( uint8_t array[], 
              unsigned int cols, 
              unsigned int rows )
{
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        unsigned int left = 0;
        unsigned int right = cols;
        int* array = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
        assert(array);
        while(left != right && right > left)
        {
            int temp = array[r * cols+ left];
            array[(r * cols) + left] = array[(r * cols) + cols - right];
            array[(r * cols) + cols - right] = temp;
            right++;
            left++;
        }
        free(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `-g` to your GCC command-line when you compile, and run your program under the GDB debugger. It will tell you exactly where the segfault is happening, as well as let you poke around and see what the variables leading to the bad access are (`info locals`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a very simple error. Your `left` and `right` indices should be moving towards each other; instead, you're incrementing both of them inside your loop.

Comment: so should I have left increment and right decrement?

Answer (score 0):

```
int* array = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
......
free(array);
```

You allocated memories, assigned its address to 'array' and the size of memory is only 1 byte. There is only 1 byte while 'cols' may be greater than 1, the size of memory is not large enough. Remove those 2 lines can fix the first issue. BTW, the variable 'array' should not be changed and you don't need a buffer to flip.

Besides, the left, right and swapping loop should be:

```
unsigned int left = 0;
unsigned int right = cols - 1;

while(left < right) {
  int temp = array[r * cols + left];
  array[r * cols + left] = array[r * cols + right];
  array[r * cols + right] = temp;

  right--;
  left++;
}
```